# Redirect User Role When on Specific Page

Tags: functions

I am trying to redirect user roles to a specific page. If their role is **contributor** and is trying to access the **Users Admin Page** they should be redirected. Not sure if I am doing this correctly as it isn't working. Please help

```
function mwd_redirect_if_on_page() {
   $mwd_current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   if ( user_can( $mwd_current_user, 'contributor')  && is_page('wp-admin/users.php') ) {
      return home_url('specific-page');
   }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'mwd_redirect_if_on_page' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal this way:

```
// Block Access to /wp-admin
function mwd_redirect_if_on_page() {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && current_user_can( 'contributor' ) && (defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && !DOING_AJAX) ) ) {
    wp_redirect( home_url('specific-page') );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'mwd_redirect_if_on_page' );
```

If you carefully see I've added ajax check. This way contributor won't be able to access `wp-admin` but still be able to other ajax requests if there any.

Answer (score 0):

That `is_page('wp-admin/users.php')` is not going to work because `is_page()` is for posts of the `page` type only and the function uses the main `WP_Query` call (which runs on page load) which doesn't happen on the `users.php` page.

But you can use the global `$pagenow` variable to check if the current admin page is `users.php`.

Here's an example using the [`admin_init` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/):

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse_385245_1' );
function wpse_385245_1() {
    global $pagenow;
    if ( 'users.php' === $pagenow &&
        in_array( 'contributor', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( 'specific-page' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Or you can instead use the [`load-users.php` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/load-pagenow/) which runs upon loading the `users.php` page, hence you would no longer need to check the `$pagenow` value:

```php
add_action( 'load-users.php', 'wpse_385245_2' );
function wpse_385245_2() {
    if ( in_array( 'contributor', wp_get_current_user()->roles ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( 'specific-page' ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

However, that hook runs only after the `admin_init` and other hooks, so if you don't want to "wait" for those extra hooks to complete, then just use `admin_init`.

**Notes:**

- `$pagenow` is an admin-side-only global variable.
- I didn't use `current_user_can( 'contributor' )` because the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) says: "*While checking against particular roles in place of a capability is supported in part, this practice is discouraged as it may produce unreliable results.*". And that also applies to the `user_can()` function.